Does spl-stake-pool support Token-2022 standard? I want my xsol or ysol to be of Token-2022 standard, Is it possible?
As in the title when i stake my sol to the stake-pool, The token that i get in return should be of Token-2022 standard. Is it possible? I don't have much idea of the spl-token pool.

It sure is possible! There are restrictions on the mint extensions allowed by the program, however, so be sure to run a test to make sure.
Note that it's not currently supported by the CLI, but the program will allow it no problem, so you'll need to write some client code to call the program. Here's the list of allowed extensions:

transfer fee
confidential transfer
default account state
interest-bearing
metadata pointer
metadata

Code at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/61cea383c1318efd0e2958e03ff709d6e4a2110e/stake-pool/program/src/state.rs#L502
